# Automate disabling ReSharper per project

Tags: resharper

I want to be able to be able to disable R# for several projects. There is quite a large number of them to be excluded which means doing it per project in VS is not ideal (Menu: R# -> Options -> Code Inspections -> Settings -> Edit items to skip).

Does anyone know have any clever suggestions? I was hoping that excluded projects/folders were stored in a R# config file I could manipulate but I haven't come across one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there's currently no way to turn off ReSharper on a per-project basis. There's a [request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-39073) for this functionality but we can't commit to any specific deadline right now.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I take it that ignoring items in 'Edit items to skip' option does not get stored in a config file?

Comment: It does get stored in [SolutionName].ReSharperVersion.ReSharper file that's in the root of your solution. Look for a XML config section that goes roughly like this: <Daemon.SolutionSettings><SkipFilesAndFolders><Item>YourItemToSkip</Item></SkipFilesAndFolders></Daemon.SolutionSettings>

Comment: Great, exactly what I was hoping for. This solves my problem 100%, many thanks!